# Memory works fine separately, but not together

Tags: memory, memtest

I've been given four 1GB Corsair DDR2 memory modules, and am trying to fit them into my computer but am getting BSOD on Windows XP and errors in Memtest86+.

I've tried to identify if one particular module is faulty by trying them in pairs. They work fine in pairs, but when all four are inserted, Memtest86+ reports errors.

The motherboard is an Asus P5N-E with dual channel support and the modules are all the same model (same speed, capacity and timings) but one pair is a different hardware revision. One is v2.1 and the other is v2.2... the voltages are the same too. Would this minor difference be a possible cause of the problem?

I've got the BIOS memory timing settings all at AUTO - should I manually set the timings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have tried both pairs, and had not errors, clearly it is due to some slight difference in the hardware. I would use "System Information for Windows" and check out your memory timings, and then compare them with a search on the Internet for the specs for your RAM, both revisions.

Then set your BIOS to match the timings to the slower spec.

http://www.gtopala.com/siw-download.html (free version at bottom)

Comment: You will love the tool regardless of whether it solves the problem. :)

Comment: I'm satisfied that the modules are not faulty. They performed fine in the previous owner's computer and they all work individually. I have changed the timing settings from Auto to 4-4-4-12 (these figures are printed on the modules themselves) and no errors yet! *touch wood*

Comment: Great, one pair was probably not being set correctly automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you tested the pairs each in the first two sockets (usually numbered 0 and 1.) Try cleaning the 2 and 3 sockets with an air duster.

Comment: I've got two yellow and two black sockets. When I was trying the pairs, I kept them in one colour (tried both yellow and black), but never put one in the yellow and one in the black. Is this the right thing to do?

Comment: No.  You did it correctly.  Some motherboards require you to always use the first two slots if you only have two sticks of RAM.  So I assumed you could have tested all the RAM  in pairs without testing all the slots.  If you're satisfied that the slots are good then I would concentrate on the BIOS settings.  Also verify that the motherboard supports the configuration you are using.