# memory DIMMs work individually, but not in pairs

Tags: memory, ddr2, dual-channel

I have four *new* (to me) sticks of Kingston 1Gb 400Mhz DDR2. Three of them boot fine individually in slots 1 or 3, but not in slots 2 or 4. The fourth does not boot in any slot.

The three working ones do not boot in any combinations of slots.

Working combinations:

```
1234 (channel numbers)
1000
0010
```

Non-working combinations:

```
1234 (channel numbers)
0100
0001
1100
0011
1010
1111 (naturally, as one stick seems duff)
```

However, with my *old* memory, a single 1Gb 667Mhz DIMM, the computer will boot no matter which channel I put the DIMM in. Any combinations of new and old also fail to boot.

Motherboard:
Gigabyte GA-M52L-S3P
[gigabyte page](http://uk.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3008#ov). Page 15 of the [manual (pdf)](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/motherboard_manual_ga-m52s-s3p_e.pdf) says that both DS/SS are useable in the usual 1&2 or 3&4 pairs, or in all four slots.

My question is similar to [Can't get memory sticks to work together](https://superuser.com/questions/313803/cant-get-memory-sticks-to-work-together), except that even combinations of known-good DIMMs do not work, and similar to [Memory works fine separately, but not together](https://superuser.com/questions/312381/memory-works-fine-separately-but-not-together), except that I can't boot the faulty stick to change the BIOS settings for it.

Comment: Of course, I didn't explicitly _ask_ a question, but I would like to know if anyone can diagnose this issue.

Comment: have u updated your bios?

Comment: No. Still F1. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Motherboard issue. If the RAM is known working (i.e. all RAM tests OK in slot 1, 1 at a time), then it's the motherboard

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that some of the motherboard timing or voltage parameters in the BIOS setup were altered from their defaults to optimize performance with the old RAM. Prior to changing RAM hardware, those settings should be returned to their defaults.