# Two 2GB DDR3 RAM sticks will work individually but not together

Tags: memory, motherboard

I've seen [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/447211/memory-dimms-work-individually-but-not-in-pairs) and some on [Toms Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3405917/ram-sticks-working.html). Both only provide **"maybe's"**, and I also wanted to understand more of the specifics of the **why's**, which is why I'm asking here.

One of our computers (Gigabyte GA-G41MT-S2) has a Transcend 2GB DDR3 1333MHz RAM installed (installed in 2011). We wanted to add more RAM, so purchased a new Transcend 2GB DDR3 1333MHz RAM.

**Problem:**
The new RAM works fine if the old RAM is removed and only the new RAM is used. If both are used together, when the system starts, nothing is shown on the monitor. There are no beeps. I see the fans rotating for around 20 or 30 seconds. Then the fans go off and around two seconds later the fans start again.
Also noticed that the old RAM has black cells on both sides, whereas the new RAM has it only on one side. In the picture below, the old RAM is on the left. New RAM is on the right. I've shown their front sides and back sides. The insides of the CPU cabinet are very clean, so I'm sure dust is not a problem.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Possible solutions indicate increasing the RAM voltage, but before trying that out, I'd like to know why that would work? I don't want to end up frying both RAM's.
Also, could anyone help out with info on why the black cells would not be present on both sides of the newer RAM and **why would that fact affect the possibility of both RAM's working together**?

Comment: You will need to whip out manual for that mobo and check if it supports two different layouts - single or double sided. There may be also the issue of so called organization or ranking. Read this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIMM#Ranking), hope you figure it out.

Comment: The fact one of the modules has 2 memory ranks is just a product engineering design choice.  Without the specification revision of your motherboard, the exact SKU of each DDR3 module you are using, information bout what firmware revision you are using.  It will be extremely difficult to even guess what possible incompatibility you happened to run into.  You verified both of these modules in the list of memory modules that Gigabyte indicates is supported by the motherboard?  It is obvious you didn't purchase identical part.

Comment: For this mobo, the 1333mHz speed is an overclocking speed.  It may only allow o.c. on a single slot at a time.  If you can find another stick of RAM that's 1066 or 800, see if that makes a difference paired to one of the 1333's.  You may just need to get into the BIOS before installing the 2nd stick and specify OC on the 2nd header, however that's done for Gigabyte.  https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-G41MT-S2PT-rev-20#sp

Comment: So the motherboard manual says "When enabling Dual Channel mode with two memory modules, it is recommended that memory of the same capacity, brand, speed, and chips be used". Odd that they say "recommended" instead of "mandatory": http://download.gigabyte.cn/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-g41mt-s2_v1.5_e.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I didn't find out the root cause of the problem, I remember the seller requested me to bring back the RAM, as it might not be compatible with the other one, and he gave me a single 4GB RAM which worked fine. The older 2GB RAM had to be kept aside.

It's sad that manufacturers don't follow common standards for hardware.