# Why won't my PC boot with 2 sticks of RAM when it will with only one of them?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3, intel-core-i5

I have 2 Corsair Vengeance 4GB DDR3 1600mhz sticks that I want to put in my MSI H81I ITX motherboard with an i5 4440 CPU

Each stick works by itself in either of the two slots, but if I insert both of them together, the PC won't boot.

The BIOS is up to date.

What could be the cause of this behavior?

---

**Edit**: Well, at least a full year later, I now know what was the problem, there was a bent pin on one of the RAM sockets, so that was it.

Comment: Have you tried different slots? For example, using slot 1 and 3 instead of slot 1 and 2?

Comment: it only has 2 slots

Comment: Take my answer with a grain of salt (because I don't know what I'm talking about) but... Could it be a power instability issue? Like maybe the PSU/clocks can barely push out the power/timings with 1 stick, but with 2 it can't hit the necessary voltages? You might try underclocking them. Looks like this happened here: https://superuser.com/questions/1268655/two-2gb-ddr3-ram-sticks-will-work-individually-but-not-together

Comment: Are you sure you have BIOS A.6 (2015-03-31), the latest and the only one with a description saying *Improved memory compatibility*? Corsair Vengeance is high-end "gaming". Maybe it's too much of a good thing for an otherwise low spec machine (old MB with H81 chipset)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was self-solved by the original poster, “…there was a bent pin on one of the RAM sockets, so that was it.” That is so idiosyncratic to the original poster’s setup that this question holds no value to other users.